# How to get command line args of c# console app with WMIC

Tags: c#, console, console-application, wmic

I have a simple C# console app that receives and argument with an ID for exec other task and wait for it.

I want to know the ID passed to C# console app with WMIC but it's empty.

The WMIC command is:

```
WMIC path win32_process where "caption='process_name.exe'" get Commandline
```

The C# console app was executed in CMD with:

```
process_name.exe 1
```

I want to capture the 1 or ID

Comment: Is the application asking for commandline arguments the same application receiving the arguments? If so, wmi is entirely unnecessary. `Environment.GetCommandLineArguments()` or from a `string[]` passed into `Main()` are better choices.

Comment: Solved @willaien thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @willaien says: Catch the args with `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` solved the issue.